# Cell in a cell excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to insert a cell in a cell? I need to divide a cell in half horizontally. I don't want to have to insert another row as I would like it to be horizontal.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using the "Merge & Center" Option,

[image: Merge & Center]

You would still be required to insert new rows though, and merge those cells that you don't want to be split. Refer below image.

[image]

Note: You are actually merging two or more rows here, to achieve the same effect as inserting multiple cells into a column.

Comment: I don't want the cells on either side to get larger.  they all need to be the same size just one column will have twice as many cells. is there a way to do that and still have the same size?

Comment: Sure, just select rows 3 and 4, and reduce their collective height to match the height of rows 2 and 5.

Comment: Clever approach!